If $\Omega \subseteq \Omega_1$, $u \in H^1(\Omega_1)$, and $u = 0$ on $\Omega_1 \setminus \overline{\Omega}$, do we have $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$?
Let $ \Omega \subseteq \overline{\Omega} \subseteq \Omega_1$ be two open, bounded domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Lipschitz boundary. Suppose $u$  belongs to the Sobolev space $H^1(\Omega)$ in such that $u = 0$ Lebesgue almost everywhere in $\Omega_1 \setminus \overline{\Omega}$. Is it the case that $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$?
This is true in dimension $n = 1$ if $\Omega = (c,d) \subset (a,b) = \Omega$ are intervals, because we have the characterization
$$ H^1_0(a,b) = \{f \in L^2(a,b) : f \text{ is absolutely continuous, $f' \in L^2(a,b)$, and $f(a) = f(b) =0$}\}. $$
If the fact is true it seems more difficult to prove in higher dimensions, where the boundaries involved can be much more complicated. By well-known results (e.g., see Chapter 5 of Evans' PDE book), we can approximate $u\rvert_{\Omega}$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ by functions in $C^\infty(\Omega)$. But we need to do more, that is, demonstrate that $u$ can be approximated in the $H^1$-norm by functions which are smooth with compact support in $\Omega$. If the result is not true in general, is it true if we place more restrictions on the regularity of the boundary?

Somewhere later in Evans' book, there is a proof of the claim that $H^1_0(\Omega) = {u\in H^1(\Omega): \ u|_{\partial\Omega}=0}$, which would solve your question

@daw Thank you, I was able to locate the statement of this result in Evans (Theorem 2 of Section 5.5 of the second edition). However, this result uses that the boundary of the domain is $C^1$. I am not sure if the result is still true if the domain has only Lipschitz boundary.
